# How can I query SQL Server table of events and dates into a column with the event as an attribute and the dates in different columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, etl, powerquery

I work with a database that has a set list of stored procedures that I am allowed to run. I have been running them with [OPENROWSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and placing the stored procedure into a temp table then querying the temp to get the dataset I need to return. Most of the stored procedures return very wide tables of dates that kind of look like this:

```
ORDER_NUMBER|STEP1_STATUS|STEP1_START|STEP1_END  |STEP2_STATUS|STEP2_START|STEP2_END |STEPN_STATUS...
12345       |COMPLETE    |01/01/2020 |02/01/2020 |INPROCESS   |01/15/2020 |02/01/2020|...
```

I would like to get a table returned that looks like this:

```
ORDER_NUMBER|STEP_NUMBER|STEP_STATUS|STEP_START|STEP_END   |DURATION_IN_DAYS`
12345       |STEP1      |COMPLETE   |01/01/2020 |02/01/2020|31
12345       |STEP2      |INPROCESS  |01/15/2020 |02/01/2020|17
```

What is the best way to do this? Alternatively, what is the best way to structure a table that has close to 100 different start and end dates. The end application for these dates are typically for business professionals working in Excel and Power Query. Thanks!

Comment: For what it's worth, the general term for this sort of operation is [tag:pivot]. It's a notorious pain in the xxx neck to do in SQL.

Comment: Are the column names and number of columns fixed?

Comment: PIVOT keyword can do this.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here is another option that will "dynamically" pivot your your data without actually using dynamic SQL

**Example**

```
Select [ORDER_NUMBER]
      ,[STEP_NUMBER] = concat('STEP',ColGrp+1)
      ,[STEP_STATUS] = [Status]
      ,[STEP_START]  = try_convert(date,[Start])
      ,[STEP_END]    = try_convert(date,[End])
      ,DURATION_IN_DAYS = DateDiff(DAY,try_convert(date,[Start]),try_convert(date,[End]))
 From  (
        Select A.ORDER_NUMBER
              ,ColGrp  = (row_number() over(order by (select null))-1)/3
              ,ColName = substring(item,charindex('_',item+'_')+1,50)
              ,ColValue = C.Value
         From  YourTable A
         Cross Apply ( values (convert(xml,(Select A.* for XML Raw)))) B(XMLData)
         Cross Apply ( 
                        Select Item  = xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)')
                              ,Value = xAttr.value('.','varchar(max)')
                         From  B.XMLData.nodes('//@*') xNode(xAttr)
                         Where xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)') not in ('ORDER_NUMBER')
                     ) C
       ) src
 Pivot (max(ColValue) for ColName in ([Status],[Start],[End]) ) pvt       
 Order By ORDER_NUMBER,ColGrp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CROSS APPLY`  You'll just have to expanded to the maximum number of STEPS in your table.

**Example**

```
Select A.ORDER_NUMBER 
      ,B.*
      ,DURATION_IN_DAYS = DateDiff(DAY,B.STEP_START,B.STEP_END)
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values ('STEP1',[STEP1_STATUS],[STEP1_START],[STEP1_END])
                     ,('STEP2',[STEP2_STATUS],[STEP2_START],[STEP2_END])
             ) B (STEP_NUMBER,STEP_STATUS,STEP_START,STEP_END)
```

**Returns**

```
ORDER_NUMBER    STEP_NUMBER STEP_STATUS STEP_START  STEP_END    DURATION
12345           STEP1       COMPLETE    2020-01-01  2020-02-01  31
12345           STEP2       INPROCESS   2020-01-15  2020-02-01  17
```